# CompletionStageのサンプルプログラムのエラーを解決したい

Tags: java, eclipse, java8

Java8,非同期処理の勉強をしていてCompletionStageクラスの勉強をしています。

質問の結論としては、**コンパイルエラーを解決したいです。**

以下のサイトのサンプルプログラムを実際に動かしています。
https://www.kannon.link/fuku/index.php/2016/11/06/01-19/

```
package java8;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO 自動生成されたメソッド・スタブ
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": main() started.");
        //Googleの株価
        CompletableFuture cf1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> downloadStockInfo("GOOG"))
                .thenApply(Main::extractClosePrices)
                .thenAccept(Main::printAveragePrice);
        //Amazonの株価
        CompletableFuture cf2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> downloadStockInfo("AMZN"))
                .thenApply(Main::extractClosePrices)
                .thenAccept(Main::printAveragePrice);
        //Appleの株価
        CompletableFuture cf3 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> downloadStockInfo("AAPL"))
                .thenApply(Main::extractClosePrices)
                .thenAccept(Main::printAveragePrice);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": main() running.");
        cf1.get();
        cf2.get();
        cf3.get();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": main() end.");
    }

    /**
     * YahooファイナンスのURLから指定した銘柄の数年分の株価情報を取得する
     * @param ticker 銘柄のID
     * @return 株価情報テーブル
     */
    private static Stream downloadStockInfo(final String ticker) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" + ticker);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": downloadStockInfo() executed. ticker " + ticker);
            return reader.lines();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 株価情報テーブルから終値を抽出する
     * @param stockInfo 株価情報テーブル
     * @return 株価情報テーブルから抽出した終値
     */
    private static Stream extractClosePrices(Stream stockInfo) {
        Stream closePricesStr = stockInfo.skip(1).map(x -> x.split(",")[4]);
        Stream closePrices = closePricesStr.map(BigDecimal::new);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": getClosePrice() executed.");
        return closePrices;
    }

    /**
     * 終値の平均値を計算し出力する
     * @param closePrices 終値の数年分のリスト
     */
    private static void printAveragePrice(Stream closePrices){
        Double average = closePrices.mapToDouble(BigDecimal::doubleValue).average().getAsDouble();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": printAveragePrice() executed. avg " + average + ".");
    }

}
```

ただしコンパイルエラーがおきました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
説明  リソース    パス  ロケーション  型
The type BigDecimal does not define BigDecimal(Object) that is applicable here  Main.java   /lucene/src/main/java8  行 57    Java 問題
The type BigDecimal does not define doubleValue(Object) that is applicable here Main.java   /lucene/src/main/java8  行 67    Java 問題
メソッド split(String) は型 Object で未定義です Main.java   /lucene/src/main/java8  行 56    Java 問題
型 Stream のメソッド map(Function) は引数 (BigDecimal::new) に適用できません Main.java   /lucene/src/main/java8  行 57    Java 問題
型 Stream のメソッド mapToDouble(ToDoubleFunction) は引数 (BigDecimal::doubleValue) に適用できません Main.java   /lucene/src/main/java8  行 67    Java 問題
```

なぜこのエラーが起きているか調べているのですが、まだ解決に至っていません。

エラーメッセージで検索をかけたり、BigDecimalやメソッド参照について調べました。

もしわかる方がいればお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ジェネリクス(総称型)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/7/technotes/guides/language/generics.html)に関するコードの問題です。エラーだけでなく、(その下に表示されている)警告の内容も見てみてください。

---

例えば

```
private static void printAveragePrice(Stream closePrices){
    Double average = closePrices.mapToDouble(BigDecimal::doubleValue).average().getAsDouble();
    ...
}
```

の `closePrices.mapToDouble(BigDecimal::doubleValue)` の部分ですが、[`mapToDouble`のリファレンス](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToDouble(java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction))を見ると

```
DoubleStream mapToDouble​(ToDoubleFunction<? super T> mapper)
```

とあるかと思います。
ここで登場している`T`は(上記リンク先のページ冒頭にある通り)`Stream`インタフェースの型パラメータであり「ストリーム要素の型」を表しますが、今回のコードでは指定されていません(`closePrices`は`Stream`型として宣言されており、パラメータ化されていない)。
このため`closePrices.mapToDouble`メソッドの引数に指定するものは`Object`型全般を`double`に変換できる必要があります(言わば`ToDoubleFunction<Object>`型)が、今回のコードで指定されている `BigDecimal::doubleValue` は(言わば) `ToDoubleFunction<BigDecimal>` 型であり、型が異なります。

---

コンパイルエラーを解消するには、型パラメータを明記します。上記のコードでいうと、

```
private static void printAveragePrice(Stream<BigDecimal> closePrices){
    ...
}
```

というように、 `closePrices`を(`Stream`型ではなく)`Stream<BigDecimal>`型として宣言します。

[コード差分](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/commit/59bfdb02d5963210d9df372e622dc2da7b8c215c)

Comment: ありがとうございます！